# Pandas not properly reading NaN cells with read_clipboard

Tags: python, pandas

The Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) for `read_clipboard` say "***Read text from clipboard and pass to read_csv**.*", but in my example below I get different resulting DataFrames with `read_clipboard` and `read_csv`. How can I get `read_clipboard` to properly read blank cells here as NaN like `read_csv` does?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import clipboard

f = StringIO()

df = pd.DataFrame({"my_column": [np.nan, np.nan]})
df.to_csv(f, index=False)
f.seek(0)

df1 = pd.read_csv(f)
f.seek(0)

text = f.read()
f.seek(0)
clipboard.copy(text)
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()

print(repr(text))
# > 'my_column\r\n""\r\n""\r\n'

print(df1)
# >    my_column
# > 0        NaN
# > 1        NaN


print(df2)
# >   my_column
# > 0        ""
# > 1        ""
```

Answer (score 1):

[`to_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html)'s first parameter is `excel` that is meant to let you paste the output to an Excel cell hence the empty strings instead of `NaN`s for the missing data. It defaults to `True`, we can change it:

```
>>> df.to_clipboard(excel=False, index=False)
>>> pd.read_clipboard()

    a
0 NaN
1 NaN
```

Comment: But I do want to be able to paste to Excel. If I set `excel=False` then the DataFrame generated by `read_clipboard` is correct but my clipboard text no longer matches the CSV generated by `to_csv`. Calling`to_csv` gives me a text .csv file with blanks for NaN and `read_csv` reads that result properly interpreting the blanks as NaN. I want that same behavior for `read_clipboard`.

Comment: For example if I save this CSV file shown in Excel https://www.screencast.com/t/kkfqA0f4Pq, `read_csv` properly gives me a DataFrame with 5 rows where 1 is NaN. But if I copy paste those cells in Excel then call `read_clipboard` the blank cell gets completely ignored. What I want is for `read_clipboard` to give the same results as `read_csv` which the docs seem to imply should happen. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Esostack Sorry, I'm a bit confused in the read/to CSV/clipboard rectangle here `:)`. But for your example CSV, `pd.read_clipboard(skip_blank_lines=False)` should do the job.

Comment: Yeah that was a bad example sorry, you're right I needed to add `skip_blank_lines=False`, but with that added I still have my original problem. I updated my question with a new example that I hope clarifies my problem. In the new code sample I don't use `to_clipboard` at all but still have a mismatch between the results of `read_clipboard` and `read_csv` reading the exact same file

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, specifying `sep='\n'` fixed it

Comment: Now after more digging I'm pretty sure it's a bug. I didn't really understand why `sep='\n'` fixed it because I didn't even have any separators in this example. Turns out it wasn't the actual sep character that mattered it was whether it used regex or not. Here's the issue I made about it https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41887 It wasn't a problem with `read_clipboard` after all, it does indeed use `read_csv` but it calls `read_csv` with `sep='\\s+'` which triggered this bug and made me think the underlying `read_clipboard` and `read_csv` methods didn't match which they do